# Covering zero-dimensional space with disjoint balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cantor-set, zero-dimensionality

Suppose that $(X, d)$ is compact zero-dimensional metric space.
That it, $X$ has basis of clopen sets.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Can we find open cover consisting of disjoint balls of radius at most $\varepsilon$?

---

This statement is true for Cantor set, as standard basis of clopen sets consists of
open balls.
We know that any such space $X$ can be embedded in Cantor set.

Initially, I thought that
those sets can be transferred via inverse image. That is if $f:X \to C$ is said embedding, and $U_i$ are open disjoint balls covering $C$,
then $f^{-1}(U_i)$ could do the job if we choose diameters of $U_i$ to be smaller than
some appropriate $\delta > 0$. We can bound diameter of those inverse images using uniform continuity on compact space. But the issue is, we can't guarantee that they will be balls in original space $(X, d)$.

---

I don't know if this is true, but for me seems likely to be. Any ideas?

Comment: Zero dimensional as what object?

Comment: @OrShahar I added clarification. I meant zero-dimensional in the sense of small inductive dimension.

Comment: If those were open sets of diameter $<\varepsilon$ then it would sound likely (or even, obvious), but here you are considering open balls. So I'd try to take a metric such that open balls are not clopen

Comment: @Jakobian Do you mean metric in which (almost) no ball is clopen? In Cantor set we have both clopen, and not closed balls. I imagine this might be the case in any embeddable space

Comment: Do you have any reason to cover it by balls? It follows directly from [SP, Tag 08ZY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08ZY) and [SP, Tag 08ZZ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08ZZ) that you can cover it by clopen subsets of diameter less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I was trying to prove Hedlund's theorem about representing topological dynamic systems with symbolic dynamic systems, and I got solution in mind that used balls. It relies on landing in first n iterations of transformation in special small balls. What I need to hold is that image of appropriately prepared ball will always fit inside some set of partition of the space. If partition was made up of balls, it would be easy.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I managed to upgrade my reasoning to use clopen cover with bounded diameter. Thanks for suggestion. I'm gonna live the question open, as it is interesting on its own.